# JavaScript $.get("curl.php",{ Array Value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to send two values from a javascript to a PHP file that in it's turn sends them to my arduino webserver. The values are strings and my wish is to send the pin value from my "pinArray" like this:

```
$.get("curl.php",{pin: pinArray[i],state:"1"});
```

But it is not working.

```
$.get("curl.php",{pin: "23",state:"1"});
```

is working fine though.

My "pinArray" looks like this:

```
var pinArray = ["23","25","27","29"];
```

The PHP file "curl.php" looks like this:

```
<?php

  $pin = $_GET['pin'];
$state = $_GET['state'];

  // Create cURL call
$service_url = 'http://arduino.local/digital/' . $pin . '/' . $state;
echo 'alert("Pin: "+ $pin +" state:  "+ $state )';
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
....
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: What's `i` at the point of the first call? And are you sure `pinArray` is defined, initialized, and in scope at that time? Any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: You cannot submit an array as an array or anything other than a string. you will need to serialize an array and post that form data to the server if that is your intention

Comment: @Epik where do you see an array being submitted?

Comment: @Epik - in jQuery you can send pretty much anything, jQuery takes care of the serializing for you, so that's not an issue, but looking at the array and assuming `i` is a number, an array isn't being sent.

Comment: But you're not expecting that `alert` to fire, are you ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like either

- `pinArray` is not defined at the time of the request
- `i` is not defined at the time of the request
- `pinArray[i]` is not defined at the time of the request

try to debug the values with chrome devotees or firebug:

```
console.log('pinArray', pinArray);
console.log('i', i);
console.log('pinArray[i]', pinArray[i]);

var data = {pin: pinArray[i],state:"1"};
console.log('data ', data);

$.get("curl.php", data);
```

Comment: I'm sure the pinArray[i] works. Everytime I press a button this command works:

    alert("Outlet:  "+idArray[i]+ "  pin:  " + pinArray[i] + " =    ON" );

How would I go about to alert in the PHP file if the command is beeing recieved and sent properly?
I'm very much a newbie in PHP.

Thanks in advance!